# Filtering list of products in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter

pls help me to arrange filtering an array with currencies in React application.
i'm rendering the list of products. And it should contain price block. i have an array of prices in different currencies. (Actually it is an array of products, which contains subArray of prices in different currencies for each product). Like this:

```
"data": {
    "category": {
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Nike Air Huarache Le",
          "gallery": [
            "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0087/6193/3920/products/DD1381200_DEOA_2_720x.jpg?v=1612816087",
            "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0087/6193/3920/products/DD1381200_DEOA_1_720x.jpg?v=1612816087"
          ],
          "prices": [
            {
              "currency": {
                "label": "USD",
                "symbol": "$"
              },
              "amount": 144.69
            },
            {
              "currency": {
                "label": "GBP",
                "symbol": "£"
              },
              "amount": 104
            },
            {
              "currency": {
                "label": "RUB",
                "symbol": "₽"
              },
              "amount": 10941.76
            }
          ]
        },
```

there is a state which contains currency, which customer choose.
the problem is that i can not arrange filter to display in card list the price in chosen currency.

```
return (
        data.category.products.map(({id, name, gallery, prices, currency, label, amount}) => 
        <div key={id} >
            <img src={gallery[0]} alt={id} />     // it works
            <p>{name}</p>                         // it also works
```

//then i'd like to filter array of prices and find an object where price.currency.label === 'USD' (for example, presume that state is USD). Then i need to show to customer price in format: $ 144.69

so i make filter like this:

```
<p>{prices.filter((item) => {
                    {/* console.log(item.currency.label) */}
                    return item.currency.label.includes('USD').label })} </p>
```

id does not work. i think OK, filter returned me an array with only position which i have to display, let's make a map

```
<p>{prices.filter((item) => {
       return item.currency.label.includes('USD').label}).map((el)=>el)} 
    </p>
```

it does not work again...

I tried many different ways, but all of them does not show neither price nor even currency. Pls help me to understand what i've missed.

Comment: Ok so I think the function you are searching for is '.find', so you can try prices.find(item => item.currency.label === 'USD').currency.label . The find function returns the first item in the array that match your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not filtering correctly, what you need to do is the following:

```
// This will return a filtered prices array, which only includes the USD currency object as the element of index 0
prices.filter((item) => {
      return item.currency.label.includes('USD')
})

// and in order to access the label you can do the following
prices.filter((item) => {
      return item.currency.label.includes('USD')
})[0].currency.lable
```

Comment: Oh, thanks!
Really, after filter we get an array with single item, and in order to get access to it we have to apply [0]. Many thanks for assaistance!